# How did my disk change from "One bad sector" to "Disk OK"?

Tags: hard-disk, smart

For a long time, SMART data told me:

[image]

Now, I got this:

[image]

So my question is: What happened to that bad sector? How did it "go away" seemingly in its own?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @ilkkachu updated the question. But the main question is how did it go from having a bad sector to having no bad sectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware of your drive mistakenly "thought" a certain sector electrical/mechanical parameters were out of normal but subsequent accesses made it "think" otherwise, so the error disappeared. I've seen it many times.

As the units of data are becoming physically smaller and smaller it's bound to happen more often than not.

To be extra sure about your disk health you may run an extended SMART test using `smartctl -t long /dev/device` or use the `badblocks` utility - but the latter only if the drive in question is not used or mounted.

Running both tests (even `smartctl -t long`) **may lead to data loss or hardware failure**, so always have fresh verified backups.

---

A little bit offtopic: I run `smartctl -t short` weekly and `smartctl -t long` monthly just to be on a safe side but to be honest SSD disks have a habit of dying out of the blue regardless but at least with mechanical rotating disks it's saved me from impeding disasters. Wikipedia has a list of SMART attributes to keep an eye on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

> But the main question is how did it go from having a bad sector to having no bad sectors?

You got there by your tool giving a confusing summary. You still have one **uncorrectable** bad sector, but the **pending** operation is gone.

Which means the firmware has completed that operation, whatever it was. As the reallocation count is still zero, no sector was reallocated during that operation.

If you **really** want to find out your current number of bad sectors, you need to read every single sector of your harddisk (bad block scan).

And keep in mind that modern harddisks reallocate bad sectors on the next write, substituting a healthy sector. That's another way a bad sector can "disappear" (but that was not what happened in your case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: So basically I still got one bad sector but not shown as it no longer pending?

Comment: That depends on how the firmware counts it - the other scenario is that you had a bad sector in both pictures, and you had a second pending operation in the first picture that could turn out to be a bad sector. So do run a bad block scan, either the internal one with `smartctl`, or an external one with `badblocks`. Then you'll know.

Comment: So I can use smartctl while using my desktop or I need a live usb stick?

Comment: You can run SMART tests while accessing the disk. No need to boot from an USB stick. However, they can take quite some time until finish, so use smartctl to get reports on the progress. You can also run `badblocks` without using an USB stick, while working normally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :)